# name 'transcribe' is not defined

Tags: python, function

```
def transcribe( s ):

    """ output: messenger RNA produced by string s
        input: a string s
    """
    if len(s)==0:
        return ''
    else:
        return one_dna_to_rna( s[0] )  + transcribe (s[1:])



 def one_dna_to_rna( c ):
        """ converts a single-character c from DNA
            nucleotide to complementary RNA nucleotide
        """
        if c == 'A': 
            return 'U'
        elif c == 'T': 
            return 'A'
        elif c == 'C': 
            return 'G'
        elif c == 'G': 
            return 'C'
        else:
            return ''
```

Comment: You have to ask a question.  You've just given two function definitions.  How were you trying to use them?  What were you expecting?  Where did you get the error?  What was the full error?  What did you try to do to solve it?  Do you have any ideas where things might be going wrong?

Comment: why is transcribe not defined?

Comment: it also said that the unindent did not match any outer indentation level.

Comment: Can you show the complete error traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'transcribe' is not defined
>>> quit()
WL-198-249:desktop vanessagill$ python -i test.py
  File "test.py", line 13
    def one_dna_to_rna( c ):
                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>

Comment: Since this is not your complete code (if ran, it would do absolutely nothing), how are you calling transcribe? Indentation errors suggest syntax errors/bad formatting of code. Beware of mixing tabs and spaces in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be reduced to the following three lines:

```
dna2rna = { 'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C' }
def transcribe2( s ):
    return ''.join(dna2rna[c] for c in s)
```

Example:

```
>>> transcribe2('ACT')
'UGA'
```

#### Discussion

Examine the reported error message:

> line 13 def one_dna_to_rna( c ): ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

This means that there is something wrong with the indentation of `def one_dna_to_rna( c ):`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have one extra space before `def one_dna_to_rna`, compared with `def transcribe`. That is most likely the cause of the indentation error.

Comment: You're right! I can't believe I didn't catch that ! Thank you so much!